# Why does invoking Array.prototype.map directly on Array instance result in an "unmodified" array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread-syntax

Why does invoking `Array.prototype.map` directly on Array instance `o` result in an "unmodified" array?

```
var o = Array(3); // [ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
o.map((x,y) => y*2); //  [ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

Instead, I have to use apply (or call):

```
Array.apply(0, o).map((x, y) => y*2)); // [ 0, 2, 4 ]
```

What am I missing?

Finally, an alternative to the above is:

```
[...o].map((x, y) => y*2); // [ 0, 2, 4]
```

I presume because this corrects whatever is missing in my original implementation.

Comment: You have an empty array, so there's nothing to iterate over

Comment: Most of the Array iterator functions skip uninitialized elements.

Comment: if you look at [].map() polyfills (real polyfills, not _ or lodash), you will see something like an `if(i in r)` filter on the elements that are mapped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does invoking Array.prototype.map directly on Array instance o result in an "unmodified" array?

Because `.map` only works on elements that actually exist. `Array(3)` creates an **empty** array of length `3`. Put differently: `.map` omites holes.

> Instead, I have to use apply (or call): ... What am I missing?

`Array.apply(0, o)` is equivalent to `Array(undefined, undefined, undefined)` in your case, i.e. you are creating an array that contains three elements.

The different becomes more apparent if you compare

```
console.dir(Array(3));
// vs
console.dir(Array.apply(null, Array(3)));
```

The first one only has property `length`, the second one also has properties `0`, `1` and `2`.

> Finally, an alternative to the above is: ...

The spread operator will call `o[Symbol.iterator]`. The iterator of an array will iterate over holes, just like you would when using a normal `for` loop.